# Отправка Post запроса Android

Tags: android, java, post

Собственно проблема заключается в том что запрос отправляется но без параметров, а именно пустая ссылка http://mysite.ru/file.php а нужно чтобы и параметр name так же отправлялся.

Заранее спасибо.

```
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://mysite.ru/file.php");

    try {           
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "nameuser"));      
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        String responseString = new String();
        HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
        if(responseEntity!=null) {
        responseString = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity);
        }          
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), responseString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // Ошибка :(
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Ошибка :(
    }
```

**Добавлено:**
Решено дело оказалось в файле.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в file.php смОтрите $_GET вместо $_POST ?

Comment: Действительно дело оказалось в файле, все работает, спасибо.